# How to complete (fill) a panel dataset with a time variable that has a delta > 1?

Tags: stata, panel-data

Say I have a bi-yearly panel only with observations at odd years, such as

```
input id year var
       1 2011  23
       1 2013  12
       1 2015  11
       
       2 2011  44
       2 2013  42
       2 2015  13
end
```

and I would like to fill up the missing *even* years. Here `year`s 2012 and 2014 is missing for all `id`s.

```
input id year var
       1 2011  23
       1 2012   .
       1 2013  12
       1 2014   .
       1 2015  11
       
       2 2011  44
       2 2012   .
       2 2013  42
       2 2014   .
       2 2015  13
end
```

- I had a look at `help expand` but I am unsure that's what I need, since it does not take the `by` prefix.
- As a background info, I need to fill up with *even* years to able to merge with another panel data-set conducted in *even* years only

Comment: Is the min and max year always the same within a given id? If so what is it? If not, is the missing value for year always in the middle or the id sequence? I.e. if the min for an id is 2005 and the max is 2011, could it be 2005 or 2011 that are missing? Or is it always one of the middle values?

Comment: Yes, in fact, the valid min and max years are the same for all `id`s. I edited the question slightly to clarify it and make the example data more representative of my data set. The missing years are all _even_ years between the _odd_ min(year) and max(year).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the panel id as `id` and the time variable as `year` and use `tsfill`:

```
clear
input id year var
       1 2011  23
       1 2013  12
       1 2015  11
       
       2 2011  44
       2 2013  42
       2 2015  13
end 


xtset id year
tsfill
```

If the min and max year is not constant across panels, you could look at the `,full` option.

```
. list

     +-----------------+
     | id   year   var |
     |-----------------|
  1. |  1   2011    23 |
  2. |  1   2012     . |
  3. |  1   2013    12 |
  4. |  1   2014     . |
  5. |  1   2015    11 |
     |-----------------|
  6. |  2   2011    44 |
  7. |  2   2012     . |
  8. |  2   2013    42 |
  9. |  2   2014     . |
 10. |  2   2015    13 |
     +-----------------+
```

Comment: A `merge` of this with a full dataset will buy you nothing unless you replace the missing values with (e.g.) interpolated values.